# DNSMasq forwarding on specific domains

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq

I've a problem of routing DNS traffic on specific domains.

Example:

- `*.swaroop.com` should forward to `ns.swaroop.com`
- `swaroop.org` should forward to `ns.swaroop.org`

Can we achieve the above scenario with DNSMasq? Please let me know if anyone has done this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following configuration in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` should be useful:

```
server=/swaroop.com/ns.swaroop.com
server=/swaroop.org/ns.swaroop.org
```

Comment: For those of you that found this like me, yes, this applies to wildcards by default. Read about it at http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html - look for `--local, --server`. It's about 1/5 of the way down.

Comment: Getting dnsmasq: bad address at line 9 of /etc/dnsmasq.conf  when added above line